# AC to DC Bridge Rectifier DC Amperage Drop

Tags: power-supply, rectifier

Assuming I used a 120 VAC -> 12 Vac 2 VA transformer and pass the current through a full wave rectifier circuit what is the maximum amperage I could draw on the DC side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 2VA transformer and "VA" means volts x amps. If your output is 12V RMS then the current you can take is up to 167mA RMS. If you take any more current you are beginning to overload the transformer and it may get too warm and eventually burn-out.

With or without a full-wave (bridge) rectifier in place, the peak current obtainable without causing problems to your transformer is going to be about 1.414 times 167mA (236mA). This is playing a bit safe and assuming a resistive load. Given that your actual load may only draw short pulses of current, the peak level for that short duration could be double or triple this amount but, without knowing the circuit or the transformer in detail this is just an intuitive guess.

Comment: Please correct-me if I'm wrong but 167mA is not the RMS current and 236mA the peak? Will not the obtainable current at a purely resistive load (PF=1) be the RMS current?

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento 167mA is the RMS current and the peak of that RMS current is 236mA. If you only draw (say) 500mA for a short duration (when voltage waveform is at max) this could also equal an overall RMS of 167mA. Meaning: extractable peak current may be 500mA (or more) but it depends on the duty cycle.

Comment: `167mA is the RMS current and the peak of that RMS current is 236mA` thanks for repeating what I said :) Anyway a peak like that would yet be considered a resistive load? It's not lagging, but it has just more like a square peak and so not a sinusoidal current waveform. Just thinking.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento I didn't repeat what you said - read your comment - you used the word "not" between "is" and "the" - that's wrong and I was being kind LOL

Comment: well, so you repeated it, `What we've got here is (a) failure to communicate` :) English is not my primary language, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply pass the current through a full wave bridge and to a resistive load, the maximum current you can draw is 150mA.

If you put a filter capacitor of typical value on the output, the maximum current you can draw is 103mA.

Ref: [**Hammond Design Guide**](http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/5c007.pdf)

Comment: Don't have the time to read the Hammond Design Guide atm but how could I increase the max current?

Comment: 1. Use a bigger transformer 2. Use a 2VA transformer with less output voltage 3. Use a switching power supply (a linear supply will *not* help) to reduce the voltage. You might be able to get (for example) 300mA at 5V.

Comment: Do you have a link to Hammond Design Guide. I found [this](http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/5c007.pdf), however when I run the numbers through a full wave bridge to a resistive load I get 1.8 amps DC.

Comment: The [**Hammond Design Guide**](http://www.hammondmfg.com/pdf/5c007.pdf) is one page and the relevant part a few lines. If you don't have time to read that (or to do a search to see) then any answer you get here will just lead to new questions, and magic smoke.

Comment: 2 VA / 12V ~= 0.17 A.  | 12V x 1.8A = 21+ Watts | Either your transformer is >> 2 VA or your Vout is << 12V.

Comment: Russell just kindly added it to my answer. The AC current is VA/voltage = 2/12 = 167mA. Multiply that by the factor shown in the guide. 0.62 or 0.9.

Comment: You know I have been running all of my calculations at 2 amps no t thinking of the fact I'm working with a transformer at 2 volt ampers.

Comment: @Russel McMahon No link was initially provided so I could not find the guide thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Loss of a typical 2VA transformer is about 0.5W (~0.4W copper + ~0.12W iron). So the available power is reduced to 1.5VA
By the definition output current of a power supply is the **average current**. If we assume that:

-Load is ohmic

-The output peaks is a sine curve (it is not entirely accurate but sufficient for this purpose)

-The ambient temperature it is not more than 45C and maximum temperature rise on the transformer is 70C...then

secondary peak voltage is about 17V minus about 1.6V drop on diodes, peak after bridge rectifier is 15.4V and average is 9.8V, then 1.5VA/9.8V=153mA